# Efficiently updating distance between points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have a data set that has n rows (observations) and p columns (features):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
p = 3
n = 5
xOld = np.random.rand(n * p).reshape([n, p])
```

I am interested to get the distance between these points in a `nxn` matrix that really has `n x (n-1)/2` unique values

```
sq_dists = pdist(xOld, 'sqeuclidean')
D_n = squareform(sq_dists)
```

Now imagine I get `N` additional observations and would like to update `D_n`. One very inefficient way is:

```
N = 3
xNew = np.random.rand(N * p).reshape([N, p])
sq_dists = pdist(np.row_stack([xOld, xNew]), 'sqeuclidean')
D_n_N = squareform(sq_dists)
```

However, considering that n ~ 10000 and N ~ 100, this will be redundant. My goal is to get `D_n_N` more efficiently using `D_n`. In order to do that, I am dividing D_n_N as follows. I already have `D_n` and can calculate `B [N x N]`. However, I am wondering if there is a good way to calculate A (or A transpose) without bunch of for loops and finally construct `D_n_N`

```
D_n (n x n)    A [n x N]
A.T [N x n]    B [N x N]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty interesting problem! Well I got to learn few new things here on the way to getting a solution on this.

**Steps involved :**

- First off, we are introducing new pts here. So, we need to use `cdist` to get squared euclidean distances between the old and new pts. These would be accommodated in two blocks in the new output, one right below the old distances and one to the right of those old ones.
- We also need to compute the `pdist` among the new pts and put its `square-formed` block along the trailing part of the new diagonal region.

Schematically put new `D_n_N` would look like this :

```
[   D_n      cdist.T
  cdist      New pdist squarefomed]
```

Summing up, the implementation would look something along these lines -

```
cdists = cdist( xNew, xOld, 'sqeuclidean')

n1 = D_n.shape[0]
out = np.empty((n1+N,n1+N))
out[:n1,:n1] = D_n
out[n1:,:n1] = cdists
out[:n1,n1:] = cdists.T
out[n1:,n1:] = squareform(pdist(xNew, 'sqeuclidean'))
```

---

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# Original approach
def org_app(D_n, xNew):
    sq_dists = pdist(np.row_stack([xOld, xNew]), 'sqeuclidean')
    D_n_N = squareform(sq_dists)
    return D_n_N    

# Proposed approach
def proposed_app(D_n, xNew, N):
    cdists = cdist( xNew, xOld, 'sqeuclidean')    
    n1 = D_n.shape[0]
    out = np.empty((n1+N,n1+N))
    out[:n1,:n1] = D_n
    out[n1:,:n1] = cdists
    out[:n1,n1:] = cdists.T
    out[n1:,n1:] = squareform(pdist(xNew, 'sqeuclidean'))
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [102]: # Setup inputs
     ...: p = 3
     ...: n = 5000
     ...: xOld = np.random.rand(n * p).reshape([n, p])
     ...: 
     ...: sq_dists = pdist(xOld, 'sqeuclidean')
     ...: D_n = squareform(sq_dists)
     ...: 
     ...: N = 3000
     ...: xNew = np.random.rand(N * p).reshape([N, p])
     ...: 

In [103]: np.allclose( proposed_app(D_n, xNew, N), org_app(D_n, xNew))
Out[103]: True

In [104]: %timeit org_app(D_n, xNew)
1 loops, best of 3: 541 ms per loop

In [105]: %timeit proposed_app(D_n, xNew, N)
1 loops, best of 3: 201 ms per loop
```

Comment: Great. This was exactly what I was looking for. A seperate question. Is it more efficient to define an ampty matrix such as `out = np.empty((n1+N,n1+N))` and fill it or instead use `hstack` and `vstack` fuctions to put these four pieces together? In MATLAB, it makes sense to pre-allocate an empty matrix. I am wondering which approach is optimum in Python. Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: of cause empty is better ! the best way is too reserve a big empty matrix at beginning, and fill it at each step.

Comment: @ahoosh If you have a lot of assignment steps, it would make sense to initialize once and then do those assignments. I guess even comparing against such three hstack/vstack combinations, initializing and assigning might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Just use cdist :

```
D_OO=cdist(xOld,xOld)

D_NN=cdist(xNew,xNew)
D_NO=cdist(xNew,xOld)
D_ON=cdist(xOld,xNew) # or D_NO.T
```

And finally :

```
D_=vstack((hstack((D_OO,D_ON)),(hstack((D_NO,D_NN)))))
```